# Is there a way selecting MULTIPLE areas of text with JS in Chrome and/or IE?

Tags: javascript, firefox, range, textnode, textrange

Firefox 3 can select MULTIPLE areas of text with JS. 
Is there a way doing this in Chrome and IE?

I really tried to find a way to select of multiple 
textareas in a web page in Chrome and IE9.

---

Infos at:
http://help.dottoro.com/ljxsqnoi.php

---

Example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/t3sWz/

---

Code FireFox3.5+ only... (but this is the question):

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        #trigger { background: yellow }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="test">
        This is some text you can highlight by dragging or clicking below.
    </p>
    <span id="trigger">
        Click here to select "This" and "some"
    </span>
    <a> - Firefox only :-(</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Get selection" onmousedown="getSelText()">
    <form name=aform>
        <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20">
        </textarea>
    </form>
    <script>
        var testCase = function() {
            var userSelection;

            if (window.getSelection) {
                userSelection = window.getSelection();
            } // No support for IE
            var textNode = document.getElementById('test').firstChild;
            var theRange = document.createRange();

            // select 0th–4th character
            theRange.setStart(textNode, 0);
            theRange.setEnd(textNode, 4);

            // set user selection    
            userSelection.addRange(theRange);

            var textNode = document.getElementById('test').firstChild;
            var theRange = document.createRange();

            // select 8th–12th character
            theRange.setStart(textNode, 8);
            theRange.setEnd(textNode, 12);

            // set user selection    
            userSelection.addRange(theRange);
        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var el = document.getElementById('trigger');
            el.onclick = testCase;
        };

        function getSelText() {
            var txt = '';
            if (window.getSelection) {
                txt = window.getSelection();
            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                txt = document.getSelection();
            } else if (document.selection) {
                txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            } else
            return;
            document.aform.selectedtext.value = txt;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm interested in the use case.

Answer (score 7):

No. Of the major browsers, only Firefox supports multiple ranges within the user selection. Other browsers (WebKit, Opera, IE9) do have the `Selection` API to support multiple ranges but do not currently support it. WebKit is [apparently not planning to add support any time soon](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-January/030102.html). As to Opera and IE, I have no idea.